# About resource limitation (MaxSubmitJob) in Slurm

Tags: ldap, centos7, slurm

I used the following command to set the maximum number of jobs a user can run.
However, the above setting did not work.
If anyone has any knowledge about this, could you please help me.

```
sacctmgr modify user account=<ldap-groupname> <ldap-username> set MaxSubmitJobs=2
```

I checked setting following command

```
sacctmgr show associations
```

outputs

```
Cluster    Account       User  Partition     Share   Priority GrpJobs       GrpTRES GrpSubmit     GrpWall   GrpTRESMins MaxJobs       MaxTRES MaxTRESPerNode MaxSubmit     MaxWall   MaxTRESMins                  QOS   Def QOS GrpTRESRunMin 
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------- ------------- --------- ----------- ------------- ------- ------------- -------------- --------- ----------- ------------- -------------------- --------- ------------- 
  clustername       root                               1                                                                                                                                                             normal                         
  clustername        root       root                    1                                                                                                                                                             normal                         
  clustername ldap-groupname                               1                                                                                                                                                             normal                         
  clustername  ldap-groupname  ldap-username                    1                                                                                                                   2                                         normal                         
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `AccountingStorageEnforce` is set to `limits` in `slurm.conf`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I was able to solve the problem by adding the following setting to slurm.conf.

```
AccountingStorageEnforce=associations 
```